# Instance method reference in property declaration

Tags: swift

I'd like to statically "configure" a BLE-related class with supported services, characteristics, notification handlers, etc., with typealiases and structs, a little like the class below. However the Swift compiler doesn't like the way I reference an instance method while declaring a `let` constant property that refers to the method (see `badCharacteristics`). What is a good way to do something similar to this? There must be a more swift-compliant way to do refer to instance methods to achieve the same goal.

I considered creating a more pared down example, but I thought a more real-world example might provide more benefit.

This is the pertinent compiler error: `Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type`

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

typealias CharacteristicData = NSData
typealias PeripheralName = String?
typealias ServiceId = String
typealias CharacteristicId = String
typealias CharacteristicNotificationHandler = (CharacteristicData, PeripheralName, CharacteristicId) -> Void

private struct SupportedCharacteristic {
    let id: CharacteristicId
    let handler: CharacteristicNotificationHandler?
}

private struct SupportedService {
    let id: ServiceId
    let characteristics: [SupportedCharacteristic]
}

class BleStuff: NSObject {
     /////// This is what I want to do:
     private let badCharacteristics = [SupportedCharacteristic(id: "1000", handler: handler1)]
     // ^^^^ Does not compile:
     // Cannot convert value of type '(BleStuff) -> (CharacteristicData, PeripheralName, CharacteristicId) -> Void' 
     // to expected argument type 'CharacteristicNotificationHandler?'

     private let badSupportedServices = [SupportedService(id: "2000", characteristics: badCharacteristics)]
     ////////

    // These declarations compile, presumably because handler1 is 
    // instantiated by the time this runs. But I don't want to do 
    // it this way...
    private var supportedCharacteristics: [SupportedCharacteristic] {
        get {
            return [SupportedCharacteristic(id: "1000", handler: handler1)]
        }
    }
    private var supportedServices: [SupportedService] {
        get {
            return [SupportedService(id: "2000", characteristics: supportedCharacteristics)]
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        supportedServices[0].characteristics[0].handler?(NSData(), "one", "two")
    }

    private func handler1(value: CharacteristicData,
                          _ peripheralName: PeripheralName,
                          _ characteristicId: CharacteristicId) -> Void {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: instead of `X.init()`, you can just say: `X()`

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the error states that the handler it was given has type

```
(BleStuff) -> (CharacteristicData, PeripheralName, CharacteristicId) -> Void
```

Not `(CharacteristicData, PeripheralName, CharacteristicId) -> Void`

The method can't exist on its own without a defined instance to call it on.

If you had an instance that would make sense to use in this context, you could change your line to:

```
private let badCharacteristics = [SupportedCharacteristic.init(id: "1000", handler: handler1(aBLEStuffInstance)]
```

This works because [methods are curried functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

This is quite indicative of bad design, however. It'd be beneficial to tell us exactly what you wish to achieve. Most likely, `handler1` should just be made `static`.

Comment: It's certainly bad design if it doesn't compile, but I'm curious if you can clarify what's bad about the design beyond that. I understand your recommendation to make the method static, and maybe for my actual use case this would be appropriate, but let's assume for discussion's sake that it cannot be. For instance, I might want `handler1` manipulate instance data. I'll try to make the question more specific.

Comment: @RobertHartman Just because it doesn't compile doesn't usually mean it's a bad design over all. The issue here is that for `handler1` to be able to manipulate instance data, it needs... an instance. Considering `badCharacteristics` is being statically initialized, the `aBLEStuffInstance` object needs to already exist, being either: a static member of `BleStuff`, or a variable outside the scope of `BleStuff`, defined in the module name space. The only situation I can think of where this were practical is if `BleStuff` was a singleton class, and you were using its singleton instance.

Comment: @RobertHartman And even in that case, it's likely better off being static in the first place.